# Saving multi-level data to Firebase from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save the data of this format (JSON):

```
{  
   "a":"aaaa",
   "b":"bbbb",
   "c":{  
      "c1":"c11",
      "c2":"c22"
   },
   "d":[  
      "d1",
      "d2",
      "d3"
   ]
}
```

to my Firebase Database from Android. How can this be achieved in one shot.
I know that a `HashMap` can be created and passed to `firbaseRef.setValue()` but how to deal with the multi-level data (like the variable `c`) and arrays (like `d`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property values (Objects) in the `Map<String,Object>` passed to [setValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)) can themselves be Maps or Lists:

```
    List<String> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    subList.add("d1");
    subList.add("d2");
    subList.add("d3");

    Map<String,Object> subMap = new HashMap<>();
    subMap.put("c1", "c11");
    subMap.put("c2", "c22");

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "aaaa");
    map.put("b", "bbbb");
    map.put("c", subMap);
    map.put("d", subList);

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test").setValue(map);
```